Was there any appeal actually filed in Trump's case against Clinton and the FBI (alleging they conspired against him)?
Back in September 2022, Trump's team filed a lawsuit in Florida against Hillary Clinton and the FBI, but:

Trump filed his sprawling lawsuit in March, naming a wide cast of characters that Trump has accused for years of orchestrating a “deep state” conspiracy against him – including former FBI Director James Comey and other FBI officials, the retired British spy Christopher Steele and his associates, and a handful of Clinton campaign advisers.
US District Judge Donald Middlebrooks dismissed the lawsuit Thursday, saying “most of Plaintiff’s claims are not only unsupported by any legal authority but plainly foreclosed by binding precedent.”
[...]
Alina Habba, an attorney for Trump, said Trump will “immediately move to appeal this decision.”

(N.B. Clinton herself was named as defendant, something that wasn't entirely clear to me from the 1st piece.)
I've done a few minutes of web searching, but I cannot find any follow-up on that appeal promise. So, did Trump's team/lawyers actually file that appeal? If so what is/was its fate?

Yes, actually, they filed earlier this year:

In a filing in the Atlanta-based 11th U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals, Trump’s lawyers argued that a federal judge’s order dismissing a lawsuit in 2022 and further ordering sanctions in 2023 against Trump and his attorneys were not justified. They also argue the sanctions “violated due process and was an abuse of discretion.”

It's mentioning Middlebrooks and Clinton, so it has to be same affair. I've not seen anything else though mentioned in the news, so if there were any developments in this appeal (that I've missed too), I'll accept that answer.
Actually, they might have filed last year in Sep. I'm not sure why The Hill posted that news with some 5 months delay as it's not covering any other developments in the case.

FWTW, looking at https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/66801076/donald-trump-v-hillary-clinton/ that's a monster case in terms of the number of participants. Even Trump's lawyers have filed for extensions to file this or that etc. given the huge scope of the case. Trump's team was even given permission to exceed the word limit for such appeals, LOL.
